# VB.NET Displaying All Form on Different Monitor

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to my 3 Forms to three of my Monitors but I can't seem to display the other 2 I can only display Form1 on my Second Monitor. Is it the wrong syntax in my code?

```
  Dim numberofmonitors As Integer = Screen.AllScreens.Length
        If numberofmonitors > 1 Then
            Me.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds
        ElseIf numberofmonitors > 2 Then
            Me.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds
            Form2.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(2).Bounds
            Form2.Show()
        ElseIf numberofmonitors > 3 Then
            Me.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds
            Form2.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(2).Bounds
            Form2.Show()
            Form3.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(3).Bounds
            Form3.Show()
        End If
```

And i also try this command

```
  Dim myScreens() As Screen = Screen.AllScreens
        If (myScreens.Length = 3) Then

            'Position form 1 in the middle of screen 1
            Me.Left = myScreens(0).WorkingArea.Width / 2 - Me.Width / 2
            Me.Top = myScreens(0).WorkingArea.Height / 2 - Me.Height / 2

            'Position the top left corner of form 2 in the middle of screen 2
            Dim myForm2 As New Form2
            myForm2.Show()
            myForm2.Left = myScreens(0).Bounds.Width + myScreens(1).WorkingArea.Width / 2
            myForm2.Top = myScreens(1).WorkingArea.Height / 2

            Dim myForm3 As New Form2
            myForm3.Show()
            myForm3.Left = myScreens(0).Bounds.Width + myScreens(2).WorkingArea.Width / 3
            myForm3.Top = myScreens(2).WorkingArea.Height / 3
        End If
```

but the problem is this command is Form3 is not displaying to my 1rst monitor/left side monitor but then the Main form is displaying to my Middle Monitor and Form2 is displaying to my Right Monitor

Comment: Looking at your first snipit, maybe switch the order of your statements around.  Since 3 is greater than 1 for example, might be everything greater is satisfying the 1st criteria and not getting a chance to be >2 or >3

Comment: @Hursey Its displaying right now but form2 and form3 is displaying on the Same Monitor (Middle Monitor)

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds
Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Form2.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds
Form2.Show()
Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Form3.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(2).Bounds
Form3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Form3.Show()
```

So i did this command someone helped me in reedit thanks anyway guys